# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 Timer

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using an Observable timer right now to open a modal for the first 15th minute and then every 24 hours.

```
 presentUpgradeModel() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(900000, 86400000);
    timer.subscribe(t => {
      if (this.shouldShowUpgradeModal) {
        this.openUpgradeModel();
      }
    });

  }
```

I am just wondering if this is consuming too many resources in the background or if there is a better way to do this? Its a mobile app so don't want to consume a lot of background processes.

Basically I just want a modal to popup every 24 hours or so.

Would setTimeout be better for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well its not only about timers its also about background app on mobiles. First of all if user close an app it will be suspended and it will not work.

If you want to have messages like that look to Push notifications.

Sure you can [use plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) to prevent background sleep but then your app will be using battery.

So to sum up better use Push notifications for notify users or you can use plugin but then no matter what your app will be using batter all the time

And lastly I would use observable for timer related things

PS. I forgot about native plugin called [Local Notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/). It allow you to schedule and even if app is closed it will still trigger a process. this could a way to go

Comment: hmm. Yeah not related to push notifications.  This is just a modalbox within the app that loads up a banner, etc. The only other option I can think of would be session storage/cookie.

Comment: @limit Problem is that no matter what you do this is mobile, and there is no guaranties that app will be active all time

Comment: @limit actually wait a moment :) i have idea